# Centering PopupPanel doesn't work on first call

Tags: gwt

I'd like PopupPanel centred in the screen calling the center() method. It is placed incorrectly the first time I load it. All subsequent times, it centers just fine.

It seems like the styles contained in < ui:style> aren't being injected. I've tried creating an interface to the style in the View (per GWT [docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Programmatic_access)) and calling ensureInjected() in the constructor but this has no effect.

How to have consistent centering?

Comment: Are you showing the PopupPanel as part of your application startup?

Comment: No, it is called later in the application. We're using the GWT [link](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture-2.html) MVP framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, this works with the following simple snippet (tested on Firefox 3.6 and Chrome 10.0):

```java
@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {

    final PopupPanel popupPanel = new PopupPanel();
    popupPanel.center();
}
```

Are you doing something differently?

Comment: The call to `show()` isn't necessary - `center()` will show the panel if it isn't already showing.

Comment: @Jason: Confirmed, works even without `show()` (the additional call to show() returns immediately, if the panel is already showing).

Comment: CreatePersonView view = new CreatePersonView(); view.setGlassEnabled(true);
view.setAnimationEnabled(true);
view.center();

Answer (score 3):

There is [a defect](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4221) which is said to be fixed in GWT 2.5. For me the issue still exists in  2.5, and for my situation the fix was to set width and height of the panel explicitly:

```
popup.setWidth("800px");
popup.setHeight("700px");
```

Comment: The issue still exists in 2.6.1 and can be remediated by this suggestion.